# How do I control radio buttons with a standard HTML button element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, leaflet

I am using leaflet and their baked-in controllers which add HTML elements that make it hard to redesign them. I want to write a script that let's me activate/deactivate each radio button with a `<button onclick="function">` so I can style my own control panel. Here is a snippet from leaflet:

```
<div class="leaflet-control-layers-base">
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> All Activities</span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons1">Beaches</span></span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons2">Wading pools</span></span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons3">Swimming pools</span></span></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

I am having issues selecting one input at a time with this:

```
  var x = $('leaflet-control-layers-selector.eq(0)').checked;
```

I have also tried `$('.leaflet-control-layers-selector:nth-of-type(1)').checked;`with little success. How do I select one by one?

Comment: What should be that `.on`?

Comment: Also `<div>` inside `<label>` is invalid HTML5 since Label's model is part of *Phrasing Content*

Comment: Also, `leaflet-control-layers-selector` as selector is just like targeting a Custom-Element tag like `<leaflet-control-layers-selector>` which is not your case. You have a **class** selector, therefore use a class selector: `.leaflet-control-layers-selector`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for the comments. I know the <div> in the <label> is bad practice. It has been a major headache for me. Like I mentioned, I can't write this HTML. It comes straight out of the leaflet library like that and I just  have to work with it. The .on should be .checked but for some reason it always returns undefined.

Comment: Could you please explain again in other words what you're actually after? You question is a bit misleading and it's hard to understand the expected result... What kind of *"control"* do you want to achieve?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I need to be able to create a function that toggles the radio buttons through an `.onclick` on `<button>` elements. This way I can just hide leaflet's bad interface (the same one that  is putting bad `<div>`tags everywhere.

Comment: Michael, I know leaflet is a *Maps Library* but I cannot figure out what you want to accomplish: on button click... do what exactly? Toggle what radio exactly? Any? Only one? And why the `innerHTML`? It's all really pretty confusing... What do you mean by "toggles"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you make a very good point about this being confusing, let me clean this up and repost.  Edits on the way

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan maybe this edit will help.

Comment: Seems a little bit more clear. Though, you have only one button, but four radio leaflet inputs... What's the idea with that one button? You want to have four `<button>` elements that you can style, and every one of them will control the leaflet inputs? I'm not sure to understand, have you tried to customize the styling using CSS instead of creating buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **styling** is your only issue, but the element positions are OK, why not use pure CSS?

```css
.leaflet-control-layers-base label input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}

.leaflet-control-layers-base label input[type=radio]+span:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  
  transition: 0.25s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #000;

}

.leaflet-control-layers-base label input[type=radio]:checked+span:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #000, inset 0 0 0 5px gold, inset 0 0 0 1em #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="leaflet-control-layers-base">
  <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> All Activities</span></div>
    </label>
  <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons1">Beaches</span></span></div>
    </label>
  <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons2">Wading pools</span></span></div>
    </label>
  <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons3">Swimming pools</span></span></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a full working example of how I have styled it in the link. My concern is having it match other styling and animation I have created with `<button>` elsewhere on the site. https://leksplay.com/waterplaymap (edit: and because of the extra `<div>` it is hard to edit the labels correctly).

Comment: @MichaelPerna sorry. I lost you :\ Your site seems quite nice and fun. PS you just have an issue on https://leksplay.com/playgroundmap - Three options checked but no markers visible on the map.

Comment: Not a problem, that particular map shows all pins matching all the criteria selected. I am still experimenting the maps and filtering, hence me being here haha.

Comment: @MichaelPerna it's incredible that leaflet uses invalid markup. One should never use `:before` or `:after` pseudos on `<input>` element (like they do). (As I already said) `<div>` should **never** end up inside a `<label>` el. Sorry for raging... you should post some serious concerns about that plugin (unless I'm missing something obvious) and file **bug/improvement reports** on their Git repo. You're welcome to link to this question and my comments. This is outrageous. The next thing I'm expecting to see there are `leaflet-foo` attributes instead of valid data-* ones...

Comment: @MichaelPerna I still don't know what is the desired input style you want to achieve... Anyways, I lost already too much time on this one and I think I'm not that helpful so far.

Answer (score -1):

Try remove your divs from inside your labels. This is probably what's causing your problem. Div is a block element, so cannot go inside a label which will only accept phrasing. (Your spans should be fine though).

Comment: Can I get rid of those `<div>` with jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: @MichaelPerna `<div>` inside `<label>` is invalid syntax, but not the major cause of your issue. This answer is actually nothing more than a repetition of an already present comment.